# Extract single value from JSON Dump response Python

Tags: json, python-2.7

I'm having some difficulties with extracting a single value from a JSON dump. I'm trying to extract the single value of a stock from JSON output generated by using the GoogleFinance package, but I keep getting this error message:

> *expected string or buffer*.

I've tried to find a solution on the forum but nothing seems to be working.

One thing I've tried is loading the JSON in to a string by using `json.loads`, but I keep running in to the same wall.

```
    from googlefinance import getQuotes
    import json
    import sys

    Apple = json.dumps(getQuotes('AAP'), indent=2) #gets the quote from Apple stock. I know I should use the json.loads but that doesn't seem to be working for the getQuotes. 


#JSON output    
    [
      {
        "Index": "NYSE", 
        "LastTradeWithCurrency": "137.24", 
        "LastTradeDateTime": "2016-11-07T13:09:43Z", 
        "LastTradePrice": "137.24", 
        "LastTradeTime": "1:09PM EST", 
        "LastTradeDateTimeLong": "Nov 7, 1:09PM EST", 
        "StockSymbol": "AAP", 
        "ID": "668575"
      }
    ]


    #Trying to solve the issue by loading the json to a string
    resp = json.loads(Apple)

    #print the resp
    print (resp)

    #extract an element in the response
    print (resp["LastTradeWithCurrency"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `resp = json.loads(Apple)` to `resp = json.loads(Apple)[0]`

Comment: Thanks @OphirCarmi It worked! Not really sure what the [0] does.

Comment: [0] takes the first element in the json list []